# Revive Ad Server my Ads Over Https returns blank

Tags: openx, advertisement-server

I have problem with my advertisement loading via https in Revive Ad Server
It returns

```
<title>Advertisement</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {margin:0; height:100%; background-color:transparent; width:100%; text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I detected problem. When I set my banner code loading via iframe then It works nice via http but Iframe tag is removed when loading via https/ssl

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Revive adserver will block all ads containing "http:" (none https-Urls) on https-delivery.